# Is the Pauli exclusion principle as Brian Cox described it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Pauli exclusion principle instantaneously affect distant electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18527/does-the-pauli-exclusion-principle-instantaneously-affect-distant-electrons)

If this rule works, could you not set up an experiment to test the theory (as described by Brian Cox in his *A Night with the Stars* lecture$^1$) and monitor another piece of diamond to see if the electrons change levels in time with the changes in energy of the electrons in the heated piece? If you used a pin point heating element that could change temperature at different frequencies, would you detect the frequency change in the monitored piece?

--

$^1$ The Youtube link keeps breaking, so here is a [search](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=brian+cox+night+with+the+stars) on Youtube for Brian Cox' *A Night with the Stars* lecture.

Comment: Related question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21677/energy-measurements-in-a-two-fermion-double-well-system

Comment: Also of relevance is [this](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/brian-cox-misunderstands-locality-pauli.html) blog discussion and [this one](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/energy-measurements-in-two-fermion.html)

Comment: This question is incomplete without state exactly what behavior you are asking about--we haven't all watched the same show. In any case, you can expect Dr. Cox to know the basics pretty well, but in the show he likes to push things for dramatic effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18527/2451

Answer (score 1):

Brian Cox's statements can be paraphrased as 'no two electrons can be in the same energy level, so if we change the energy level of any electron in the Universe, then all the other electrons will change energy levels - so we are all connected'.

This is essentially true except that he said "energy level" instead of "quantum state" (which for some reason caused a lot of controversy on Twitter). See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASZWediSfTU), which is called "Was Brian Cox wrong?".

Pauli's exclusion principle has, I assume, been measured. Although, I don't know if you could measure it in the way you suggested.