# Expectation of an Observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, integration, linear-algebra, observables

If we have the complex scalar
$\langle f|\Omega|g\rangle$ as in equation (2.73) of [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_04.pdf) course notes (where $\Omega$ is Hermitian), and want to evaluate it in the position basis, I would proceed as follows:

$\langle f|\Omega|g\rangle  =\iint dx \ dy\langle f|y\rangle  \langle y|\Omega|x\rangle  \langle x|g\rangle  =\iint dx \ dy \ (f(y))^{*}g(x)\langle y|\Omega|x\rangle \quad \quad \mathbf{(1)} $

However, said notes claim that

$\langle f|\Omega|g\rangle=\int dx \ (\Omega f(x))^{*}\ g(x)=\int dx \ (f(x))^{*}\Omega \ g(x) \quad \quad \mathbf{(2)}$

which I don't understand. I'm okay with the first equality in $\mathbf{(2)}$, but have an issue with the second one. $(\Omega f(x))^{*}$ is really $\langle \Omega f | x\rangle=(\langle x|\Omega|f\rangle)^{\dagger}$, so I don't see how the $\Omega$ can just be plucked out.

**Context**:

I want to evaluate the expectation $\langle \hat{O}\rangle_{\psi}$ of observable $\hat{O}$ using the position basis. By my usual approach in $\mathbf{(1)}$,
$\langle \psi| \hat{O} | \psi \rangle=\iint dx\ dy \ (\psi(y))^{*}\psi(x)\langle y|\hat{O}|x\rangle$
but if this can be whittled down to
$\langle \psi| \hat{O} | \psi \rangle=\int dx \ \|\psi(x)\|^{2}\langle x|\hat{O}|x\rangle$
then I'd like to know if that is indeed possible! I was trying to follow part 2 of Valerio's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377078/making-indistinguishable-particles-distinguishable?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: It looks like your second line is abusing some notation. I am also not sure where the double integral went

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one! For full disclosure I was trying to understand Valerio's expansion in part 2 of his answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377078/making-indistinguishable-particles-distinguishable?noredirect=1&lq=1. I'll add this to the context part of my question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an abuse in notation other than what you were saying. Putting $\langle f|\Omega|g\rangle$ and $\Omega g(x)$ in the same equation is pretty poor notation.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's be familiar with the notation given on your [source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_04.pdf).

Consider a Hermitian operator $\Omega$ so that
$$\Omega=\Omega^\dagger$$

Look at the matrix element of $\Omega$ in some basis
$$\langle u|\Omega|v\rangle=\langle u|\Omega v\rangle$$
or $$\langle u|\Omega|v\rangle=\langle u|\Omega^{\dagger}|v\rangle=\langle \Omega u| v\rangle=\langle u|\Omega v\rangle$$

---

Note the following
$$\Omega|v\rangle=|\Omega v\rangle$$ and

$$\langle u|\Omega^\dagger=\langle \Omega u|$$

---

Now for functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)\in \mathcal{C}$
$$\langle f|g\rangle=\int(f(x))^*g(x)dx$$
where * means complex conjugate. Also for Hermitian operator, we have proved above:
$$\langle \Omega f| g\rangle=\langle f|\Omega g\rangle$$
The quantity of interest
$$\langle f|\Omega|g \rangle=\langle \Omega f| g\rangle=\langle f|\Omega g\rangle$$

In position basis we can directly write
$$\langle \Omega f| g\rangle=\int(\Omega f(x))^*g(x)dx$$
and $$\langle f|\Omega g\rangle=\int(f(x))^*(\Omega g(x))dx$$
$$\int(\Omega f(x))^*g(x)dx=\int(f(x))^*(\Omega g(x))dx$$

Note that $\Omega $ is still a abstract operator because we don't know its matrix element $\langle x|\Omega|x'\rangle$ in position basis. But this doesn't change the equality of those two.

---

You can do them another way:

$$\langle f|\Omega| g\rangle=\int \langle f|x\rangle\langle x|\Omega|g\rangle dx=\int (f(x))^* (\Omega g(x))dx$$
or $$\langle f|\Omega| g\rangle=\int \langle f|\Omega|x\rangle\langle x|g\rangle dx=\int (\Omega f(x))^* g(x) dx $$
which are equal.